# Web development in Visual Studio (not ASP.NET) - Is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio, web

I've wondering if it's possible to use visual studio (2013) to develop a HTML5 based website (HTML5-CSS-jQuery-etc), like Dreamweaver (which I hate by the way). Working with MVC Views was so easy because of IntelliSense, so that's why basically asking this. I want make a webpage, but the only option is ASP.NET...

For all those who are going to ask: Yes I've searched about this, but all the tutorials were about ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012+ offers built-in support for HTML5 as explained in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618298.aspx. You can create an empty web site and write your code/markup in it.

For the earlier 2008-2010 versions there is a VS extension:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d

Comment: You mean an empty C# website project?

Comment: You could create an ASP.NET Empty Web Site.

Comment: Thanks for that!, now do you know if it's possible to enable RewriteEngine and other modules? Because visual studio runs a local server different from WAMP (which im currently using)

Comment: Or maybe IIS Server doesn't have those modules... I don't know really